# Passing Variables to another file

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, sharepoint-2007

I have two ascx files, I am trying to pass a variable from the first ascx file which basically just grabs data, to the second ascx file which displays data based off the first one. Is there anyway to do this. They are both contained within the index.aspx page file. It will be displayed on a SharePoint site.